# How do i convert decimal value to single digit

Tags: javascript

Here is my question

I want to convert 0.21 to 0.29 to 2

then 0.31 to 0.39 to 3 till 0.99 to 9

and so one

I went to this function but it didn't help

```
function myFunction() {
    var num = 0.89;
    var n = num.toFixed(1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n +1;
}
```

Comment: *"I want to convert 0.21 to 0.29 to 2"* What about `0.2`?

Comment: From 0.21 to 0.29 into 2?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following:

```
function myFunction(num) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.floor(num*10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to achieve what you want is:

```js
var num = 0.89;
var n = Math.floor(num * 10) % 10;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Without using any math functions. Because you want X of 0.XYZ every time.

Comment: `toFixed` rounds.

Comment: AFAIK that 0.765.toFixed(2) will return "0,77" with the current culture's separator.

Comment: 0.89 should be 8 also i don't want decimal in final answer

Comment: Then you should use `Math.floor`

Comment: @TahaPaksu: *"AFAIK that 0.765.toFixed(2) will return "0,77" with the current culture's separator"* That's incorrect: https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-number.prototype.tofixed But my point was that `(0.29).toFixed(1)` is `3` whereas the OP clearly said they want `2`.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: I don't know the ES6+ implementations, but MDN says: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed **formats** the number.

Comment: @TahaPaksu: After rounding it, yes, and with `.` in all locales. This is trivially easy to check, and hasn't changed since `toFixed` was added long before ES2015.

Comment: Yes, but I think the main thing here is that the output is a string. not a number, and therefore the "+" operator will concatenate it. not add it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use factor for flooring.

```js
function format(v) {
    var d = Math.floor(Math.log10(v));
    return Math.floor(v / Math.pow(10, d));
}

console.log([0.2, 0.89, 0.023, 5432].map(format));
```

Comment: OP wants 8 not 0.8

Answer (score -1):

```
var integer_value = Math.floor(num*10); // gives required integer value
```

**Explanation:**

If your number is 0.ABC, you want A, you can do this by multiplying 0.ABC by 10, which makes it A.BC and then using [Math.floor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) on A.BC to get A.

**Cases:**

When 0.ABC:

- 0.012 --> Math.floor(0.12) ---> 0
- 0.213 --> Math.floor(2.13) ---> 2
- 0.290 --> Math.floor(2.90) ---> 2
- 0.988 --> Math.floor(9.88) ---> 9

**toFixed(0)**

[toFixed(sig_digits)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) will give you a string representation of the number till a certain number of significant digits. Using that with sig_digits 0, will round it off, so cases like 8.99 will get rounded off to 9, instead of 8.